# When Arriving at AngularJS-driven site, routed to / instead of actual link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a site built with AngularJS. I use $routeProvider to define a bunch of routes. They all work fine when I am in the site already. Let's take the following:
rooturl.com#/services/myservicename

When the website is already open, on say the homepage at "#/", then everything is working fine, it routes to rooturl.com#/services/myservicename and loads the right content.

Now, say I open a new browser, paste rooturl.com#/services/myservicename into the address bar, I get to my website, but I am routed to content for "/" instead of rooturl.com#/services/myservicename.

It's basically the same as here:
[AngularJS routes with parameters in path not loading in HTML5 mode when going directly to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472224/angularjs-routes-with-parameters-in-path-not-loading-in-html5-mode-when-going-di)
...except I do not have this line, so I am not sure if the discussion about $locationProvider documentation applies to me?

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Moreover, I am on a corporate intranet. I will NOT be able to get access to the server. Is there any client-side thing I can do, within the code of my angular site, to allow a user to  enter rooturl.com#/services/myservicename in the address bar, and always reach that route?

Note sure which code is more important to the answer, but here is my .config in the app definition. The rest of the code that follows it are controllers and services.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
    .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/home_tpl.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
    .when('/support/:subject',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/support-process.html',
            controller: 'SupportProcessCtrl'
        })
    .when('/support/:subject/:topic',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/support-process.html',
            controller: 'SupportProcessCtrl'
        })
    .when('/projects',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/project_list_tpl.html',
            controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
        })
    .when ('/site-help',
        {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/site-help.html'
        })
    .otherwise(
        {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/404.html'
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The html5 mode being true allows you to omit the # from your route.

It looks like you may be missing a slash from your url.

rooturl.com#/services/myservicename

should probably be

rooturl.com/#/services/myservicename

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to change anything. If I go to rooturl.com/#/services/myservicename instead, I still end up at my homepage (initial route, aka "/"). Is there something I need to setup in my config?

Comment: Also let me clarify, I'm testing this in IE8, which I must support, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Change your otherwise to actually redirect to a route.
A couple of things to check:
- Change your otherwise to a named route; i think it is a good practice .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
- Also I do not see a defined route for your url in your config at all.  How are you using this url in your app?

Comment: is my setup for .otherwise actually impacting linking? And what do you mean 'defined route'? Can you give me a snippet of what you mean? When I'm in the application, all links execute exactly as expected, loading the partials, running the controllers.

Comment: Guess I am unclear if, in a normal simple implementation of angular, without express or anything doing any additional deep-link handling from the server, whether rooturl.com/#/services/myservicename should execute the desired partial controller that I had defined in $routeProvider if I input the full link rooturl.com/#/services/myservicename in the address bar, or if I need to add settings to the above to allow that. I've not been able to identify anything more I should need to do, since I have few dependencies here, just using $routeProvider.

Comment: Hi Max - Sorry I have been out for a bit.  Can you get a working code sample up somewhere so I can take a look?  I feel like we could comment back and forth for a while and I would really like to get this resolved for you.

Comment: SO your route is /services/myservicename right.  I do not see a .when("/services/myservicename", {})  Maybe you are just using filler names for this.  What route are you trying to access?

Comment: Yeah, I should say, for example, /support/services/myservicename, .when('/support/:subject/:topic',